# Vue.js - Editing SessionStorage Data

Tags: vue.js

I have a sessionStorage item (cart) which I saved from a form. I also have a button that lets you edit your cart items. What i want to do is whenever the user edits the cart items, the sessionStorage gets updated. How do i do this using vue?

Vue.js Code:

```
window.onload = function () {

new Vue({
  el: '#cart-items',
  data () {
    return {
      cart: ''
    }
  },
  mounted () {
    if(sessionStorage.cart) {
        const cart1 = sessionStorage.cart;
        this.cart = JSON.parse(cart1);
    }
  },
  computed:{

  },
  methods:{

  }
})
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set a `watch` on this variable, and update the `sessionStorage` every time it changes:

```
watch: {
    cart: function(val) {
      sessionStorage.setItem("cart", val);
    }
}
```

If you want a better technique, take a look at [`Vuex`](https://vuex.vuejs.org/).

Comment: Thanks! Can you use vuex without using vue-cli?

Comment: Yes of course. You can install it normally using ``npm``. But I advise you to read the documentation well before using it.